# Postman Test value given matches expected results, but still get an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, postman

I'm trying to test this search function to look for a specific entry on my server file on Postman, but the tests keep failing, even though I believe my code is returning the desired outcome.

It's expecting the results to be "pm.expect(jsonData.name).to.eql('Three Rivers Campground')", Isn't that what is happening below? The server is returning a JSON object where it's .name is equal to 'Three Rivers Campground'.

Postman Test Code:

```
pm.test("name check", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.name).to.eql('Three Rivers Campground');
});
```

Server Code + Search Method

```
const campgrounds = [{name: "Three Rivers Petroglyph Site", town: "Lincoln, NM", lengthLimit: 25, elevation: 4986, numberOfSites: 7, padType: "gravel"},
                     {name: "Baca Campground", town: "Lincoln, NM", lengthLimit: 32, elevation: 6397, numberOfSites: 7, padType: "dirt"},
                     {name: "South Fork Campground", town: "Nogal, NM", lengthLimit: 19, elevation: 7513, numberOfSites: 60, padType: "unknown"},
                     {name: "Valley of Fires Recreation Area", town: "Carrizozo, NM", lengthLimit: 38, elevation: 5249, numberOfSites: 19, padType: "asphalt"},
                     {name: "Oak Grove Campground", town: "Alto, NM", lengthLimit: 25, elevation: 8464, numberOfSites: 30, padType: "unknown"},
                     {name: "Three Rivers Campground", lengthLimit: 25, elevation: 6332, numberOfSites: 12, padType: "dirt"},
                     {name: "Silver Campground", town: "Cloudcroft, NM", lengthLimit: 30, elevation: 8956, numberOfSites: 30, padType: "gravel"},
                     {name: "Springtime Campground", town: "Magdalena, NM",  elevation: 7381, numberOfSites: 6, padType: "dirt"},
                     {name: "Bear Trap Campground", town: "Magdalena, NM", lengthLimit: 21, elevation: 8497, numberOfSites: 4, padType: "grass"},
                     {name: "Datil Well Campground", town: "Datil, NM", lengthLimit: 35, elevation: 7414, numberOfSites: 22, padType: "dirt"},
                     {name: "Apache Creek",  town: "Reserve, NM", lengthLimit: 19, elevation: 6397, numberOfSites: 10, padType: "gravel"},
]

app.get('/search', (req, res) => {
    let searchTerm = req.query.q;
    console.log(`Search for ${searchTerm}`);
    for(var i = 0; i<campgrounds.length; i++){
        console.log(campgrounds[i].name)
         if (searchTerm == campgrounds[i].name){
             
            return res.json({campgrounds: campgrounds[i]});
         }
        }
})
```

I test this and get this error on Postman:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6SF9.png)

The code my function is returning:

```
{
    "campgrounds": {
        "name": "Three Rivers Campground",
        "lengthLimit": 25,
        "elevation": 6332,
        "numberOfSites": 12,
        "padType": "dirt"
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be `jsonData.campgrounds.name` if that's what is being returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to change this line : "return res.json({campgrounds: campgrounds[i]});"
into " return res.json(campgrounds[i]);"